# Remove UIDatePicker's color

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

IS it possible to remove UIDatePicker's color ?(means color bar that exist around of it)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to remove the UIDatePicker's color. Try using a UIPickerView with different components and prepare a custom UIDatePicker if you want. Hope this helps!!