# UIDatePicker highlights today's date - how can i change that color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker highlights today's date in it's blue color, but I'd like it to use a different color for this. How can i change it?

Answer (score 5):

You can't, not without recreating `UIDatePicker` from scratch. If you want this ability, please request it at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `UIDatePicker` is not customizable via a delegate like `UIPickerView`. If you need this functionality, your best bet is probably to create your own custom date picker from a `UIPickerView`.

You'll have to code up all the date logic though.

If you need more help. Please refer to this link:

[How to change Font of UIDatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796921/how-to-change-font-of-uidatepicker)

[Remove UIDatePicker's color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097677/remove-uidatepickers-color)

Hope this helps you.